# Highlight a table cell but without the padding area

Tags: html, css, hover, padding

I have a table column  and there are other divs inside of this table column. On mouse hover, I want to highlight all of the content (multiple divs inside the ). I have got this working but here is the problem.

The  also has some padding from 4 sides. When I apply the CSS :hover effect, I don't want the padding area to be affected. Rather, everything else inside the div excluding the padding area should be highlighted.

Here is the html

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:120px;">
            <div>SomeStuff</div>
            <div>SomeMoreStuff</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the css

```
#MyTable td { /* added only for visualisation */
    border:1px solid red;
}
#MyTable td:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

[JsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5QxJ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9zzcY/

Change the HTML to:

```
 <td style="padding:20px;">
   <div class="tdContentWrapper">
    <div>SomeStuff</div>
    <div>SomeMoreStuff</div>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Change the CSS to:

```
#MyTable .tdContentWrapper:hover{
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Arbel, works perfectly ! However, I was thinking if there is a CSS property where in you can specify if your padding area should be highlighted or not.

Comment: There is no such CSS property for changing the background color of the padded area, but you can simulate it by changing the background color of the table cell (or highlighting it as you name it) and assigning the cell's default background color (the color of the padded area before changing) to the content block of the cell, in this case .tdContentWrapper so that it will look like only the padded area has changed background color. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9zzcY/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change your style declaration to :

```
td:hover div {
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. 
My CSS is as below

#MyTable td:hover div {background:black;}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
td:hover div{
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting an inner markkup to your design witch will not overflow the padding.

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:120px;">
            <div class="inner-td">
                <div>SomeStuff</div>
                <div>SomeMoreStuff</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And apply styling to the 'inner-td' divider **on** the td:hover

[jsFiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5QxJ/1/)

```
#MyTable td { /* added only for visualisation */
    border:1px solid red;
}
#MyTable td:hover .inner-td {
    background: black;
}
```

Also, Note that **:hover on anything other than `<a>` elements is not fully supported** in many older browsers.

Comment: Did you replicate what I had written 15 minutes before you?

Comment: Although the two solutions are similar - both answers are great. Thanks for your help .